# rust pyo3 bindings import DLL error when use tch

Tags: rust, pyo3

I use PyO3 to write the python bindings with rust.

My code do simple  work which is a demo from pyo3 documentation , but simpily add  "**use  tch**" in  this  module, comiple is ok, but failed when runing. These codes are  meaningless just for debugging. I keep it as simple as possible.

**My LIBTORCH env:**

```
$env:LIBTORCH
C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch
$env:LIBTORCH_USE_PYTORCH
1
```

**My pyo3 codes:**

```
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use tch;

/// Formats the sum of two numbers as string.
#[pyfunction]
fn sum_as_string(a: usize, b: usize) -> PyResult<String> {
    Ok((a + b).to_string())
}

/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
fn pyo3_example(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(sum_as_string, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

**And my cargo.toml:**

```
[package]
name = "pyo3-example"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "pyo3_example"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
pyo3 = "0.19.0"
tch = "0.14.0"
```

**And my test.py:**

```
import pyo3_example as  example
print(example.sum_as_string(2,3))
```

Then run: **python test.py**

Reports the folloing error:

```
import pyo3_example as e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jerry\CloudStation\dev\.env\Lib\site-packages\pyo3_example\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyo3_example import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pyo3_example: The specified module could not be found.
```

If I removed the **use tch** from my pyo3 codes. It worked.

I tried use pdb, but can't step into the import line.

I want to know:

1. what's the problem?
2. or how can I debug it to find which DLL tailed to load?

I tried as  above, use pdb to find the missed DLL, but I can't step into the rust codes.

Comment: `use tch;` links the `tch` crate, without it it won't be linked.

Comment: `tch` requires libtorch to be on your system; do you have it?

Comment: yes, cargo.toml depends on tch. And libtorch lib is installed . It can work with pure rust codes.

Answer (score 0):

I change the runing platform to linux, then it works. So I close the question.

Forget windows.